# Rails app page source

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it normal for a rails app to get all this code in the page source and for all website pages?
I am posting this question because i have seen the source page of lot off rails app but can't arrive to see something like this

```
  <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/font-awesome.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/companies.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/custum_style.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/dashboard.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/errors.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/jobs.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/pages.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/posts.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/profiles.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/resumes.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/reviews.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/saved_jobs.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/statuses.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/welcome.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.core.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.theme.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.accordion.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.menu.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.button.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.datepicker.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.resizable.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.dialog.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.progressbar.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.selectable.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.slider.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.spinner.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.tabs.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.tooltip.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.base.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.all.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.core.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.widget.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.accordion.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.position.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.menu.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.button.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.datepicker.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.mouse.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.draggable.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.resizable.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.dialog.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.droppable.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-blind.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-bounce.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-clip.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-drop.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-explode.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-fade.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-fold.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-highlight.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-pulsate.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-scale.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-shake.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-slide.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-transfer.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.progressbar.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.selectable.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.slider.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.sortable.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.spinner.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.tabs.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.tooltip.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.all.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/tinymce/preinit.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/tinymce/tinymce.jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/tinymce-jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/affix.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/alert.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/button.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/carousel.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/collapse.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/dropdown.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/tab.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/transition.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/scrollspy.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/modal.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/tooltip.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/popover.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/companies.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/dashboard.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/errors.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jobs.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/pages.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/posts.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/profiles.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/resumes.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/reviews.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/saved_jobs.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/statuses.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/welcome.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="Ib6fW6ouyDHKT3Bs+/DiJDFbGZziC1IazzyejBE7ugU=" name="csrf-token" />
```

for more details this is my gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "jquery-ui-rails", "~> 4.2.0"
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', "~> 3.1.0.0"
gem "tinymce-rails", "~> 4.0.18"
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.2.0'
```

this is my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require tinymce-jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require_directory .
```

Comment: All the assets are present as individual files. You are not using [`rails asset pipeline`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)?

Comment: But i have this gems gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails' in my gem file

Comment: what rails version are you using? Are you [`precompiling assets individually`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets)

Comment: I'm using 'rails', '4.0.2' and i don't precompile assets individually and my app is in run in development if that can help

Comment: and i'm also not using turbolink

Answer (score 0):

The Rails asset pipeline only compiles individuals assets into the digest when running in the Production environment. It is possible that the site you are looking at is running their application in Development or has opted to not use the asset pipeline.

Comment: This is my site and the application is running in Development so you think this is normal?

Comment: If it's live on the server then you would want to be running in the Production environment. You'll be able to utilize the asset pipeline and a number of other Rails features (such as caching) that are disabled in development.